# How to pull latest from a specific remote branch without having need to provide user details?

Tags: c#, git, git-pull, pull, libgit2sharp

#### Requirement:

Using [libgit2sharp](https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2sharp) I want to pull (fetch + merge) latest from a **specific git remote branch** to my **currently checked out local branch**, without having to pass any other argument, like user credentials etc. Basically I am trying to replicate `git pull origin my-remote-branch`

#### Details:

I want to automate certain Git operations from C#. I can simply do what I want by invoking `git.exe` (if I know the path), like `git.exe --git-dir=my-repo-directory pull origin my-remote-branch`. Notice that here the only external parameters I have to supply are `my-repo-directory` and `my-remote-branch`. Git gets everything right, like the name, password, email, current working branch (even if it doesnt have remote attached) and git pull simply works. I dont have to pass any of those parameters manually. I assume Git gets them from current Git settings for the repo (from %HOME% folder?).

Is there a way to simulate that in LibGit2Sharp?

#### What I tried:

```
using (var repo = new Repository("my-repo-directory"))
{
    PullOptions pullOptions = new PullOptions()
    {
        MergeOptions = new MergeOptions()
        {
            FastForwardStrategy = FastForwardStrategy.Default
        }
    };

    MergeResult mergeResult = Commands.Pull(
        repo,
        new Signature("my name", "my email", DateTimeOffset.Now), // I dont want to provide these
        pullOptions
    );
}
```

Which fails since it says `there is no tracking branch`. I dont necessarily need a tracking remote branch. I just want to fetch latest from a specific random remote repo and perform automerge if possible.

Just to see if it works I tried:

```
using (var repo = new Repository("my-repo-directory"))
{
    var trackingBranch = repo.Branches["remotes/origin/my-remote-branch"];

    if (trackingBranch.IsRemote) // even though I dont want to set tracking branch like this
    {
        var branch = repo.Head;
        repo.Branches.Update(branch, b => b.TrackedBranch = trackingBranch.CanonicalName);
    }

    PullOptions pullOptions = new PullOptions()
    {
        MergeOptions = new MergeOptions()
        {
            FastForwardStrategy = FastForwardStrategy.Default
        }
    };

    MergeResult mergeResult = Commands.Pull(
        repo,
        new Signature("my name", "my email", DateTimeOffset.Now),
        pullOptions
    );
}
```

This fails with

> request failed with status code: 401

#### Additional info:

I dont want to invoke git.exe directly because I cant hardcode the git exe path. Also, since I cant pass username, email etc at runtime, is there a way libgit2sharp get them by itself from the repository settings, like how git.exe does?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> I assume Git gets them from current Git settings for the repo (from `%HOME%` folder?).

It depends entirely on what the remote "origin" is:

- an ssh URL (in which case Git will rely on `%HOME%\.ssh`). ssh support for libgit2sharp is followed by [issue 7](https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2sharp.nativebinaries/issues/7) and (rejected) [PR 1072](https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2sharp/pull/1072): you might have to use [`leobuskin/libgit2sharp-ssh`](https://github.com/leobuskin/libgit2sharp-ssh)
- an https URL (in which case Git should rely on a [Git credential helper](http://leobuskin/libgit2sharp-ssh) (see [Git Storage](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Credential-Storage)), which is [not supported directly by libgit2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44253498/6309), as [mentioned here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23980406/6309).
  You will have to code that helper yourself in CSharp: "[Retrieve Credentials from Windows Credentials Store using C#](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17747020/6309)".
  Or, as [commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46833568/how-to-pull-latest-from-a-specific-remote-branch-without-having-need-to-provide/46894580#comment80806318_46894580) by [Edward Thomson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/729881/edward-thomson):

  > Pass a `CredentialsHandler` in your `FetchOptions`.
  >   Return either `UsernamePasswordCredentials` or `DefaultCredentials` from your handler, as appropriate.

[See  here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36062476/6309) for a `UsernamePasswordCredentials` example.
See also [`LibGit2Sharp.Tests/TestHelpers/Constants.cs`](http://LibGit2Sharp.Tests/TestHelpers/Constants.cs#L8-L35) and [other occurrences](https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2sharp/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=UsernamePasswordCredentials%20&type=).

---

Regarding the pull operation, it involves a [Command `Fetch`](https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2sharp/blob/2f8ad262b7613e9e68aefd4f55956bf24b05d042/LibGit2Sharp/Commands/Fetch.cs#L27-L35), which involves a **[refspec](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Internals-The-Refspec)**. As in "[Git pull/fetch with refspec differences](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7169390/6309)", you can pass the `source:destination` branch names for your pull (even if there is no tracking information).

That is what is used in [`LibGit2Sharp.Tests/FetchFixture.cs`](https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2sharp/blob/2f8ad262b7613e9e68aefd4f55956bf24b05d042/LibGit2Sharp.Tests/FetchFixture.cs#L129-L153).

```
string refSpec = string.Format("refs/heads/{2}:refs/remotes/{0}/{1}", remoteName, localBranchName, remoteBranchName);
Commands.Fetch(repo, remoteName, new string[] { refSpec }, new FetchOptions {
                TagFetchMode = TagFetchMode.None,
                OnUpdateTips = expectedFetchState.RemoteUpdateTipsHandler
}, null);
```

Comment: Will have a look at this later and get back to you.

Comment: @nawfal OK. A simple "git remote -v" is a good start to know what kind of URL you are dealing with. And since your main issue is 401 (lack of valid authentication), this answer is about addressing authentication issue.

Comment: the problem is even if I manage the user credentials, what would be the API to specify the branch I want to pull from?

Comment: @nawfal First, let's resolve the authentication issue. Then, if you have setup the tracking branch (https://stackoverflow.com/a/42660436/6309) a simple pull will be enough.

Comment: Hmm, maybe I wasnt clear enough in the question, but I don't want to set a tracking branch. If I do I am messing up with other developers' settings. This is a part of automating pull operations from various remote branches for all the devs. But I think a quick fix would be set it and then reset it to its original tracked branch.

Comment: @nawfal Then you need to pass in the pull option the name of the remote branch you want to pull from. But remember: the question is first about authentication: as long as it is not solved, no git command involving a remote will work.

Comment: I will work on authentication and all the steps later. Just skimming through the source code I dont see the option to specify remote branch in pull options.

Comment: @nawfal you do so by specifying a refspec: https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2sharp/blob/master/LibGit2Sharp.Tests/FetchFixture.cs#L129-L153 (https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Internals-The-Refspec) like https://stackoverflow.com/a/7169390/6309

Comment: @nawfal I have edited the answer to include the pull branch specification part.

Comment: I do not see a way to pass in the username/password in either Pull or Fetch. Those test cases dont but succeed and I dont see how.

Comment: @nawfal yes you can: the parameter is the refspec you set in the fetch option: it will include the local branch name, remote name (origin) and the remote branch name from which you want to fetch.

Comment: True, `refspec` has branch details. I am talking about credential details. Where in to pass it? I keep getting `401`.

Comment: First, what is your remote url? An https one or an SSH one?

Comment: @nawfal to set credentials with Fetch, pass a `CredentialsHandler` in your `FetchOptions`.  Return either `UsernamePasswordCredentials` or `DefaultCredentials` from your handler, as appropriate.

Comment: @EdwardThomson Thank you. I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.