# Lib2GitSharp: Git Pull <remote> <branch> (e.g. git pull origin main)

Tags: c#, git, git-refspec, lib2gitsharp

I'm looking for a code snipping to archive the `git pull <remote> <branch>` with Lib2GitSharp. Imagine you are on a branch `feature/1` and you want to pull the latest changes from `main`.

If have the following code up to now:

```cs
var mergeOptions = new MergeOptions
{
   FastForwardStrategy = FastForwardStrategy.Default,
   CommitOnSuccess = true,
};

var remoteBranch = repo.Branches[remoteBranchName];
Commands.Fetch(repo, remoteBranch.RemoteName, new string[0], fetchOptions, $"Fetch from '{remoteBranch.RemoteName}'");
repo.Merge(remoteBranch.Tip, merger, mergeOptions);
```

This is working fine as long FastForward is possible. It even ends up with the exact same result as the "standard" `git pull origin main`

The difference is happening when FastForward is not possible. In this case Lib2GitSharp is creating this commit:

[image: Merge commit ...]

And Git is creating the following commit:

[image: Merge branch feature/1 ...]

After that I found another [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46833568/how-to-pull-latest-from-a-specific-remote-branch-without-having-need-to-provide). There it was recommended to use RefSepcs together with Merge.
I prepared the following code snippet based on the documentation, but it's just performing no action at all. No change to the repo after executing it:

```cs
var refspecs = $"refs/heads/feature/1:refs/remotes/origin/main";
Commands.Fetch(repo, currentBranch.RemoteName, new string[1] { refspecs }, pullOptions.FetchOptions, null);
repo.MergeFetchedRefs(merger, pullOptions.MergeOptions);
```

Can someone please recommend the right code to archive this with Lib2GitSharp.

Comment: what language are you coding in?

Comment: c# (Lib2GitSharp)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```cs
var mergeOptions = new MergeOptions
{
   FastForwardStrategy = FastForwardStrategy.NoFastForward,
   CommitOnSuccess = true,
};

var remoteBranch = repo.Branches[remoteBranchName];
Commands.Fetch(repo, remoteBranch.RemoteName, new string[0], fetchOptions, $"Fetch from '{remoteBranch.RemoteName}'");
repo.Merge(remoteBranch, merger, mergeOptions);
```

The change I did was to not use `remoteBranch.Tip` in the merge.